# How can I know whether the users actually shared a deep link to their facebook timeline or not?

Tags: android, cordova, deep-linking, branch.io

I am integrating Branch to my Cordova app, I am able to create a deep link through branchUniversalObj.showShareSheet(), however, from the below existing event callbacks results, there seem no flag to indicate that whether the users clicked Cancel or Post buttons from the facebook share modal dialog, it just tells the client that there is a Branch deep link created.

```
    Branch.createBranchUniversalObject Response:  {"message":"Success","instanceId":0}
    index.js:170 branchUniversalObj.onShareSheetLaunched OK
    index.js:180 branchUniversalObj.onChannelSelected {channelName: "Facebook"}
    index.js:176 branchUniversalObj.onLinkShareResponse {sharedLink: "https://0n1z.test-app.link/XXX", sharedChannel: "Facebook"}sharedChannel: "Facebook"sharedLink: "https://0n1z.test-app.link/XXX"__proto__: Object
    index.js:173 branchUniversalObj.onShareSheetDismissed OK
```

My question is, is there a way to know whether the users actually posted this link to their facebook timeline or not? In other words, how do I know whether the users tapped the Cancel or Post button in the facebook share modal dialog?

This is critical requirement for me to integrate Branch to my app. Any help is very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use these listeners to know if a link share was successful:

```
// optional listeners (must be called before showShareSheet)
branchUniversalObj.onShareSheetLaunched(function (res) {
  // android only
  console.log(res)
})
branchUniversalObj.onShareSheetDismissed(function (res) {
  console.log(res)
})
branchUniversalObj.onLinkShareResponse(function (res) {
  console.log(res)
})
branchUniversalObj.onChannelSelected(function (res) {
  // android only
  console.log(res)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's correct, I called these events and as you can see my description already included the event output. This issue only happens on android device, the event branchUniversalObj.onLinkShareResponse() was finished before the facebook share modal dialog's dismiss, the button Cancel or Post was even not pressed yet. On ios, it worked properly, the event was only triggered after tapped on Cancel or Post button from the facebook share modal dialog. Any idea why this is different behavior on android?